# Export excel data to Parse.com database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want all the rows from excel sheet to get exported to Parse database. Is there a way to do it. I searched the doc but not able to find one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this pls 
**http://blog.parse.com/2012/03/09/one-click-export/** it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just save your Excel sheet as a Comma Seperated Variable (CSV) file and then import it.
To import, go to your Parse.com profile and then into the Data Browser. Click Import button and upload the CSV file. That's it.